# Issues with a nested element's destruction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested

I created a form to allow a user to create an album via two scaffolded generation (one for the album, the other for the photos themselves). I'm trying to make a link where the user can see a "delete" button that would destroy the picture. There would be a small alert to confirm the picture's destruction, then the picture would get destroyed and the browser would reload the page with the successful notice.

My main problem is that I tried to reach the selected picture, however I think Rails messes up between the photo's id and the album's id.

Here is my code:

**view/edit.html.erb**

```
<h1>Editing Album</h1>

<%= render 'form', album: @album %>

<% @album.photos.each do |p| %>
    <%= image_tag p.image %>
    #Attempt to reach the photo and to destroy it
    <%= link_to 'Destroy', @photo, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Show', @album %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', albums_path %>
```

**album_controller.rb**

```
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_album, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  #...

  def create
    @album = Album.new(album_params)

    if @album.save
      # to handle multiple images upload on create
      if params[:images]
        params[:images].each { |image|
          @album.photos.create(image: image)
        }
      end
      redirect_to @album, notice: 'Your album has been created.'
    else
      render :new, alert: 'Something went wrong.'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @album.update(params[:album].permit(:title,:description))
      # to handle multiple images upload on update when user add more picture
      if params[:images]
        params[:images].each { |image|
          @album.photos.create(image: image)
        }
      end

      redirect_to @album, notice: 'Album has been updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @album.destroy
    redirect_to albums_url, notice: 'Album was successfully destroyed.'
  end

  private

    def set_album
      #Attempt to select individually the album and the photos
      @album = Album.find(params[:id])
      @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    end

    def album_params
      params.require(:album).permit(:title, :description, :user_id, :image)
    end
end
```

**photos_controller.rb**

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_photo, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # trucated for space

  def update
    if @photo.update(photo_params)
      redirect_to @photo, notice: 'Photo was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @photo.destroy
    redirect_to :back, notice: 'Photo was successfully destroyed.'
  end

  private
    def set_photo
      @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    end

    def photo_params
      params.require(:photo).permit(:album_id, :image)
    end
end
```

**model/photo.rb**

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :album
  validates_presence_of :album
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

end
```

**model/album.rb**

```
class Album < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :photos
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, allow_destroy: true
end
```

When I try to delete an image, this works, I can't find the picture in my "upload" folder, however, when I try to reload the page, I get the following error: `Couldn't find Photo with 'id'=4`, targetting the line `@photo = Photo.find(params[:id])`

My question is : how can I target and delete a picture in a proper way without getting these kinds of error?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `params[:id]` in your `AlbumController` as both the id of the album *and* the id of the photo:

```
@album = Album.find(params[:id])
@photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
```

This doesn't make any sense, you will get nonsensical results from this. You should remove the second line (so *just* fetch the album), and in your view reference `p` (from the `each` loop) and not `@photo`:

```
<% @album.photos.each do |p| %>
  <%= image_tag p.image %>
  <%= link_to 'Destroy', p, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I corrected the redirection, however I still get the same error, even after restarting the server. I'll check if this correction works if I delete a photo from a new album

Comment: Ah actually, sorry it is redirecting back to your *album* edit action. Can you show what you have for that? (you didn't include it above)

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: So I created a new album with pictures in it, deleted my line (`@photo = Photo.find(params[:id])`), but when I tried to edit the album, Rails failed to recognize what 'photo' was standing for. That's what I'm trying to make him guess since earlier..

Comment: Sorry not `photo`, should be `p`. It's the `p` in the `each` loop. If you had `@album.photos.each do |photo|` it would be `photo` (this is more the convention, which is why I originally wrote `photo` without looking closely at the code).

Comment: Thank you, it worked ! -- This seems so obvious why it didn't work before now !

Comment: You're welcome! Just remember that `params[:id]` is (in general) the id of the record of the main thing you are dealing with, in this case the album.